# My text gets rendered as image when using html2pdf

Tags: javascript, html2pdf

So basically i am making a html page using for loop that generates qr code and text side by side. The first problem is that the text is rendered as image and so it is not searchable, secondly the my margins get split in between the pages. If anyone can help me to fix these please.

I am using html2pdf by EKOOPMANS

```js
$('#cmd').click(function () {
document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  var element = document.getElementById('content');
  
  html2pdf(element,
 {html2canvas:  {scale: 4,letterRendering: true, logging:true },filename:"Qr",margin:[5,0,0,0]})
  
});


for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
  if (i == 1) {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '<section  style="padding-top:5px;padding-right:60px; page-break-inside:avoid; "  class="container"> <div class="container" > <div style="border-top:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black;border-left:1px solid black;"    class="ticket"><div class="left" > <div class="ticket-info"><div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-top: 105px; font-size:15px;margin-right:-15px; margin-left:-20px">    Ο </div><div class="col-sm-9"><div style="padding-top:8px;padding-bottom:8px;" id="qrcode' + i + '"> </div></div></div></div></div> <div class="container"> <div class="row"> <p style="margin-top:100px;margin-left:30px;font-size:33px; font-weight:bold;">O01-OPA-C-000000' + i + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </p> <p style="font-size:15px; margin-top:115px; margin-left:-20px">     Ο  </p> </div> </div> </div>  </div></section>';
  } else if (i < 10 && i >= 2) {

    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '<section  style="page-break-inside:avoid; padding-right:60px;  "  class="container"> <div class="container" > <div style="border-top:1px solid black ;border-right:1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black;border-left:1px solid black;"    class="ticket"><div class="left" > <div class="ticket-info"><div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-top: 105px; font-size:15px;margin-right:-15px; margin-left:-20px">    Ο </div><div class="col-sm-9"><div style="padding-top:8px;padding-bottom:8px;" id="qrcode' + i + '"> </div></div></div></div></div> <div class="container"> <div class="row"> <p style="margin-top:100px;margin-left:30px;font-size:33px; font-weight:bold;">O01-OPA-C-000000' + i + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </p> <p style="font-size:15px; margin-top:115px; margin-left:-20px">     Ο  </p> </div> </div> </div>  </div></section>';
  } else if (i <= 99 && i >= 2) {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '<section  style="page-break-inside:avoid; padding-right:60px;  "  class="container"> <div class="container" > <div style=" border-right:1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black;border-left:1px solid black;"    class="ticket"><div class="left" > <div class="ticket-info"><div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-top: 105px; font-size:15px;margin-right:-15px; margin-left:-20px">    Ο </div><div class="col-sm-9"><div style="padding-top:19px;padding-bottom:8px;" id="qrcode' + i + '"> </div></div></div></div></div> <div class="container"> <div class="row"> <p style="margin-top:100px;margin-left:30px;font-size:33px; font-weight:bold;">O01-OPA-C-00000' + i + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </p> <p style="font-size:15px; margin-top:115px; margin-left:-20px">     Ο  </p> </div> </div> </div>  </div></section>';
  } else if (i <= 999 && i >= 2) {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '<section  style="padding-top:-5px;padding-right:60px; page-break-inside:avoid; "  class="container"> <div class="container" > <div style=" border-right:1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black;border-left:1px solid black;"    class="ticket"><div class="left" > <div class="ticket-info"><div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-top: 105px; font-size:15px;margin-right:-15px; margin-left:-20px">    Ο </div><div class="col-sm-9"><div style="padding-top:19px;padding-bottom:8px;" id="qrcode' + i + '"> </div></div></div></div></div> <div class="container"> <div class="row"> <p style="margin-top:100px;margin-left:30px;font-size:33px; font-weight:bold;">O01-OPA-C-0000' + i + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </p> <p style="font-size:15px; margin-top:115px; margin-left:-20px">     Ο  </p> </div> </div> </div>  </div></section>';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '<section  style="padding-top:-5px;padding-right:60px; page-break-inside:avoid; "  class="container"> <div class="container" > <div style=" border-right:1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black;border-left:1px solid black;"    class="ticket"><div class="left" > <div class="ticket-info"><div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-top: 105px; font-size:15px;margin-right:-15px; margin-left:-20px">    Ο </div><div class="col-sm-9"><div style="padding-top:19px;padding-bottom:8px;" id="qrcode' + i + '"> </div></div></div></div></div> <div class="container"> <div class="row"> <p style="margin-top:100px;margin-left:30px;font-size:33px; font-weight:bold;">O01-OPA-C-000' + i + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </p> <p style="font-size:15px; margin-top:115px; margin-left:-20px">     Ο  </p> </div> </div> </div>  </div></section>';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.8.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-vDKWohFHe2vkVWXHp3tKvIxxXg0pJxeid5eo+UjdjME3DBFBn2F8yWOE0XmiFcFbXxrEOR1JriWEno5Ckpn15A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<div id="content" class="html-content">
</div>
<button style="margin-left: 300px; width:500px" id="cmd"  class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
```

This is how I am generating my html file. The pdf is downloading fine but the text specifically the "O01-OPA-C-0000001" is rendered as image so the pdf is not searchable.

Comment: Please add a minimal reproduction of your code to your question.

Comment: I have shared the JS code i am using to generate pdf

Comment: What css/html are you using? This could well be significant.

Comment: Added everything i am using

Comment: You are missing the QRCode code. Either remove this from the code, or add the missing references.

Comment: The Second for loop is for the QRCode ?

Comment: The code in your snippet does not work because the QRcode reference is missing. Please edit it to work.

Comment: Again the issue is not the QR code but the text which is generated in the first FOR loop. That text is rendered as image in html2pdf and i need a fix for that

Comment: I get that! But your code DOES NOT RUN because of the QR code stuff. Please remove it if it is not relevant!

Comment: Oh My bad. I have removed the for loop with the QR code. I have also added the button and through button click i am generating the pdf

Comment: Can you please tell how do i do that in my code?.. Like edit my existing code or something?.. Will be very grateful

Comment: " That text is rendered as image in html2pdf and i need a fix for that" from a very quick read of the documentation I believe that it will always be an image i.e. "The basic workflow of html2pdf.js tasks (enforced by the prereq system) is:

.from() -> .toContainer() -> .toCanvas() -> .toImg() -> .toPdf() -> .save()"
Again this is ONLY from a 5 minute read of the documentation for the html2pdf.js

Answer (score 0):

html2pdf.js does great client-side rendering, but it is fundamentally limited because of its approach of using HTML Canvas to build the PDF. This limits both the size and the content, since the pdf is just a "picture" of what is on the page, saved as a PDF.

You cannot generate a text-based PDF using html2pdf.js.

According to [eKoopmans' html2pdf.js README](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js#issues)

> Known Issues:
>
> 4. Rendered as image: html2pdf.js renders all content into an image, then places that image into a PDF.
>
>    This means text is not selectable or searchable, and causes large file sizes. This is currently unavoidable, however [recent improvements in jsPDF](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF) mean that it may soon be possible to render straight into vector graphics.